# What is the determinant of a matrix that commutes with a complex structure?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is known that if $A \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear complex structure (i.e. $A^2 = -I$) and $B \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $B^TAB = A$, then $\det(B) = 1$.

But what can we say about $\det(B)$ if it’s invertible and $B^{-1}AB = A$? Is it necessarily positive?

Comment: What is the definition of the complex structure?

Comment: $A\in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a complex structure if $A^2 = -I$.

Comment: Lukas Heger: I’m asking about the determinant of $B$, not $A$. In any case, this question was already answered.